# changing xticks and yticks

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

After fitting the kNN-classifier with the scaled features (age and salary), I would like to plot the resulting diagram with the unscaled feature values.

[kNN-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leame.png)

I think that one way to do this is to change the xticks and yticks of the plot and leave everything like it is. Hopefully someone has got a better idea.

Moreover, it would be great if the diagram can show the correct (age / salary) values in the bottom left corner, when I go with the cursor over the diagram.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that. Therefore, I am asking of help.

The dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2mfr2kajrm7y2qq/AADFmZzYWLEjqYSLPjaQcLwka?dl=0

The code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values.astype(float)
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values

# splitting into training and test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.75, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)

# no fit, because it is test
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# fitting kNN classification to the training set
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the Test set result
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


# Visualising the Test set results
f = plt.figure()
X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
f.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I noticed that the answer to my answer is pretty simple...
I thought too complicated.

However, this is the solution:

We just have to add the following lines:

```
wished_xticks = np.array([18, 22, 35])
temp_x = np.c_[ wished_xticks, [0]*len(wished_xticks) ]
transformed_x = sc_X.transform(temp_x)[:,0]
plt.xticks(transformed_x, wished_xticks)

wished_yticks = np.array([17000, 25000, 100000, 150000])
temp_y = np.c_[ [0]*len(wished_yticks), wished_yticks ]
transformed_y = sc_X.transform(temp_y)[:,1]
plt.yticks(transformed_y, wished_yticks)
```

So, we get our wished result:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q1ml.png)